# ASP ADO Connection

Tags: asp-classic, addition, records

i want to make connection of ASP to a database and display the records, add update and delete them all in one coding. Waiting for your kind response.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to do an ADO tutorial- there [is a good one here](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/default.asp).